Graphviz set positions to start from (0,0) and increment ny 1 unit?
I have a graphviz graph generated and I am using networkx to read that graph and assign them position values i.e nx.nx_pydot. The thing is the node values are very random like (1854,234) and so on. Is there any way i can get them to scale to to start from (0,0), (0,1) and so on?
original_pos=nx.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(graph,prog='dot')

Can you provide your code so that we can reproduce?

Which program is assigning the positions - graphviz or networkx? Graphviz uses points as position units (1/72 inch), so (0,0) and (0,1) are very close to each other.
